# Showing that no local isometry exists between two surfaces.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, surfaces

Consider the surfaces:
$$\tag{2}
\begin{equation}
\Sigma=\left\{\left(x, y, \log \left(\frac{\cos (x)}{\cos (y)}\right)\right) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid-\frac{\pi}{2}<x, y<+\frac{\pi}{2}\right\}
\end{equation}
$$
$$
\Sigma^2=\begin{equation}
\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\right\}
\end{equation}
$$
I want to show that there does not exist a local isometry from $\Sigma$ to $\Sigma^2$. I believe we can use Gauss theorem, which says that the Gaussian curvature $K$ of a surface is invariant by local isometries. I found that the Gaussian curvature of $\Sigma$ is
$$
\begin{equation}
K_{\Sigma}=-\left(\frac{\sec x \sec y}{1+\tan ^2 x+\tan ^2 y}\right)^2
\end{equation},
$$
whereas the Gaussian curvature of the unit sphere, $\Sigma^2$ is everywhere equal to 1,
$$
K_{\Sigma^2}=1
$$
Since there does not exist $(x,y) \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ such that $K_\Sigma=K_{\Sigma^2}$, we can conclude from Gauss theorem that there does not exist a local isometry between the surfaces.

Is there anything wrong with my argument?

Comment: It is easier to argue that the first curvature function is nonconstant.

Comment: @MoisheKohan How's that? Is my statement wrong that it follows directly from Gauss theorem since $K_{\Sigma}\ne K_{\Sigma^2}$? Now that I already know the Gaussian curvatures.

Comment: No, nothing is wrong with your proof, I just find it is easier to check that the curvature is nonconstant than to check that it does not take the value 1 at any point.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. But recall that $sec(x)>1$ in the entire domain. Hence, $K_{\Sigma}<0$ in the domain, so it does not need to be proven that it does not take value $+1$.

Comment: One curvature is $>0$, the other is $\leq 0$, goodnight (constancy versus non-constancy and precise values are irrelevant here).

Comment: I was going to add something along the lines of what @Ivo just said. Scherk's surface is a minimal surface and hence has negative Gaussian curvature everywhere. That is the end of the story :)

Comment: Okay, thank you. :)

Comment: Don't delete questions like that. Of you realize the question was not too difficult z simply add an answer yourself.